# Redis: storing intermediate set results, use random names or wrap in transaction?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I'm having to do get a result based on the intersection of multiple unions of (sorted) sets.

E.g.

```
Intersect(Union(A,B), Union(C,D), E)
```

The obvious way of doing this is storing Union(A,B) and Union(C,D) in temporary sets and using those in the final intersection command.

But obviously, those temporary sets need a name and despite Redis being single-threaded, if I use fixed names for it, I'll run into concurrency problems.

My solution has been to do the entire 'query' in a MULTI/EXEC-block (create the temporary sets, do my intersection, fetch the results, delete the temporary keys).

The obvious alternative is to not use MULTI/EXEC but use sufficiently random names for those temporary sets.

My question is: which is preferable/best practice?

The former probably comes with a performance (/availability to other threads) penalty but the latter adds complexity and isn't guaranteed not to cause concurrency problems.

Haven't really looked that much into doing it in Lua, but I'm assuming that'll make it even more complex.

Comment: I would refrain from deleting the key in the transaction. Deleting a key is O(n), see http://openmymind.net/Redis-SlowLog-and-DEL-surprisingly-bad-performance/ for alternatives.

Comment: I think in general the solution really depends on the exact situation,  Is there a specific reason you cannot keep a Union_A_B and Union_C_D around, or even always have them procomputed?

Comment: Mmm, that's a trade-off with memory though. There are a lot of possible permutations here. Keeping all possible union-sets stored would eat up a lot of memory to speed up something that currently isn't a bottleneck.

Comment: But you implied leaving them around would cause issues with concurrencies, could you give an example of how this could go wrong?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that. I meant to say, deleting them after usage without a multi/exec-block would cause concurrency issues. If we leave them around, this wouldn't happen on the condition they're properly named after their contents (e.g. your UNION_A_B rather than TMP_STEP_1). Same applies to the end result btw (as there's no ZINTER, just a ZINTERSTORE), so that'd need a more descriptive name as well (which it currently doesn't).

Comment: One tweak on your option is to create a temp set (guid name etc...) and right after creating, put an EXPIRE on it just in case you fail/crash.  You can also create the temp set with a name like TEMP:<guid> so on startup, delete TEMP:*.  that even catches a crash after the create but before you set the EXPIRE